# Accessing a database cursor and closing it

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have following code:

```
Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    do {
                        //do stuff
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
cursor.close();

query = "<some sql code>";
cursor = mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
```

1. Can I close the cursor, and then open it again by making another query-call with .rawQuery?
2. Is it ok to not check the cursor for null when doing cursor.moveToFirst()? As I understand it, the query can only return 0 results, which wouldn't be a problem when doing .moveToFirst?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but it isn't doing what you seem to think it is.  You aren't reopening the cursor.  You're setting the variable to reference a new cursor for the new query.

I've seen null returns from db queries.  I'd keep the null check.  The amount of overhead is minimal.

Comment: Okay, thank for your answer! Do you happen to know why the query might return null?
So should I close the cursor before referencing it, or is it sufficient to close the cursor at the end?

Comment: `query()` or `rawQuery()` *never* return `null`. Only content providers might return `null`. (When the cursor is empty, `moveToFirst()` returns `false`.)

Comment: @CL. I'm fairly certain I've seen it.  I have null checks in some of my code for it and I almost never add those reflexively.  But of course I can't prove it either.

Comment: @GabeSechan Have a look at the source code ([SQLiteDatabase](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java), [SQLiteDirectCursorDriver](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java#L43)); these functions return either with a valid `Cursor` object, or through an exception. You'd need a buggy cursor factory (are you ever using one?).

Comment: @CL. You're assuming that OEMs didn't make any changes of their own to AOSP (they do all the time) and that it didn't return null in some past version.  Neither are assumptions I would make enough to say it can't return null.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close%28%29) about `close()` says the you would not be able to use the cursor again:

> Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it
>   completely invalid. Unlike deactivate() a call to requery() will not
>   make the Cursor valid again.

If you are using the cursor in an adapter you can close the old cursor after you set the new one. `swapCursor()` returns the old Cursor, or returns null if there was not a cursor set, also returns null if the if you try to swap the same instance of the previously set cursor. Knowing that, you can try something like this:

```
Cursor c = adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

if(c != null)
    c.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but cursor.requery() isn't the same as cursor.rawQuery(), plus I am referencing a new cursor for the query, or am I wrong?